# How to remove from for/each loop only instance of declared type but not actual?

Tags: java

Example:

```
 Car carOne = new Toyota("Camry");
 Toyota carTwo = new Toyota("Corolla");
```

Both of them are in ArrayList. How with help of for/each loop I can remove only `carOne` but not `carTwo`? I have tried `instanceOf` and it removes both items

Comment: do you want to know the type of the object?

Comment: What is wrong with comparing the *brand* (Camry/Corolla) and removing based on result?

Comment: @kofhearts i guess yes otherwise how you can remove the right one?

Comment: @Adarsh can you post the example please?

Comment: Try `list.remove(carTwo);`

Comment: @BorisRuzanov I mean (If I get your requirement correctly): `for (Car car : list) { if (car.getBrand().equalsIgnoreCase("Camry")) // it's Car else // it's Toyota }`. On the other hand, if your requirement is to know if the object is being referenced by `Parent class (Car)` or the class itself (`Toyota`), I think there is no way to know that in a loop.

Comment: To safely remove from a collection while iterating over it you should use an Iterator.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. If you already have a reference to the object (or if `Toyota` properly overrides the `equals` and `hashCode` methods), `list.remove(carOne)` will just work.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to collect all the objects that you want to remove by using an enhanced for loop and after you finish iterating, remove all found objects. For instance, Let's assume that your objects blue prints looks something like this:

```
abstract class Car {
    public abstract String getModel();
}

class Toyota extends Car {
    
    private String model;
    private String color;
    
    public Toyota(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
    
    public Toyota(String model, String color) {
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
    }
    
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "[model: " + model+ ", color:" + color + "]";
    }
}
```

You've a collection of cars like this:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
cars.add(new Toyota("Prius", "Red"));
cars.add(new Toyota("Camry", "Red"));
cars.add(new Toyota("Corolla", "Red"));
cars.add(new Toyota("Prius", "Blue"));
cars.add(new Toyota("Camry", "Blue"));
cars.add(new Toyota("Corolla", "Blue"));
```

Now, you want to remove only the cars that are Camrys. Collect the list of cars whose model is "`Camry`".

```
Car camry = new Toyota("Camry");
List<Car> camryList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        
for (Car car: cars) {
    if (car.getModel().equals(camry.getModel())) {
        camryList.add(car);
    }
}
```

Finally remove the `camryList` from `cars`:

```
System.out.println("Cars before removal: " + cars.toString());
System.out.println("Removing cars: " + camryList);
cars.removeAll(camryList);
System.out.println("Cars after removal: " + cars.toString());
```

Another option is to use `ListIterator` which has support for removal and addition of items during the iteration itself. It looks like this:

```
Car camry = new Toyota("Camry");
ListIterator<Car> iter = cars.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getModel().equals(camry.getModel())){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

If you're using JDK* or later, you can make use of the removeIf method like this:

```
Car camry = new Toyota("Camry");
cars.removeIf(x -> x.getModel().equals(camry.getModel()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing carTwo is easiest done with method java.util.List.remove:**

```
cars.remove(carTwo);
```

**See method remove in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car carOne = new Toyota("Camry");
    Toyota carTwo = new Toyota("Corolla");
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(carOne, carTwo));
    System.out.println("List of cars before removal of carTwo:\t" + cars);

    cars.remove(carTwo);
    System.out.println("List of cars after removal of carTwo:\t" + cars);
}
```

**Output:**

```
List of cars before removal of carTwo:  [Toyota{model='Camry'}, Toyota{model='Corolla'}]
List of cars after removal of carTwo:   [Toyota{model='Camry'}]
```

**See Car interface:**

```
public interface Car {
    // Intentionally empty
}
```

**See Toyota child class:**

```
public class Toyota implements Car {
    private final String model;

    public Toyota(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override 
    public String toString() {
        return "Toyota{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**============================**

**Remove carTwo with foreach loop:**

**============================**

**Note:** This alternative is **NOT** recommended, just to answer the original qustion with foreach loop.

In this example index of the list cars will be found in order to remove the instance of carTwo, just to make it diffrent from first example.

We will compare class refernce to find carTwo index.

**Class Object's toString() is used to get class reference:**

```
super.toString()
```

**See this approach in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car carOne = new Toyota("Camry");
    Toyota carTwo = new Toyota("Corolla");
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(carOne, carTwo));
    System.out.println("List of cars before removal of carTwo:\t" + cars);

    int index = -1;
    for (Car car : cars) {
        if(car.getClassReference().equals(carTwo.getClassReference())) {
            index = cars.indexOf(car);
        }
    }

    cars.remove(index);

    System.out.println("List of cars after removal of carTwo:\t" + cars);
}
```

**Output:**

```
List of cars before removal of carTwo:  [Toyota{model='Camry'}, Toyota{model='Corolla'}]
List of cars after removal of carTwo:   [Toyota{model='Camry'}]
```

**See Car interface (method is added):**

```
public interface Car {
    String getClassReference();
}
```

**See changed Toyota child class:**

```
public class Toyota implements Car {
    private final String model;

    public Toyota(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Toyota{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public String getClassReference() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

**Alternative to:**

```
int index = -1;
for (Car car : cars) {
    if(car.getClassReference().equals(carTwo.getClassReference())) {
        index = cars.indexOf(car);
    }
}
```

**cars.stream():**

```
    int index = cars.stream()
            .filter(car -> car.getClassReference().equals(carTwo.getClassReference()))
            .map(car -> cars.indexOf(car))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            .get(0)
            .intValue();
```

Comment: Is this satire?